# Conditional data depends on generic type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, generics

Basically I'm using a React function based component.

*** But the question has nothing to do with React specificly.

```js
const Component = <Condition extends boolean>(props: React.PropsWithChildren<Props<Condition>>) => {
```

Props:

```js
interface Props<Condition extends boolean> {
  condition: Condition;
}
```

In this function, I create a variable to store some data.

```js
  const initialValues: Fields<Condition> = (() => {
    const base = {
      unit: '',
    };

    if (props.condition) {
      return {
        ...base,
        from2: '',
      };
    }

    return base;
  })();
```

The `Fields` type is configured as following:

```js
interface Base {
  unit: string;
}
interface Extended extends Base {
  from2: string;
}

export type Fields<Condition extends boolean> = Condition extends true ? Extended : Base;
```

The entire code organized together:

```js
interface Base {
  unit: string;
}
interface Extended extends Base {
  from2: string;
}

export type Fields<Condition extends boolean> = Condition extends true ? Extended : Base;

interface Props<Condition extends boolean> extends PropsFromState {
  condition: Condition;
}

const Component = <Condition extends boolean>(props: React.PropsWithChildren<Props<Condition>>) => {
  const initialValues: IJobFormFields<Condition> = (() => {
    const base = {
      unit: '',
    };

    if (props.condition) { // Check if condition (also Condition type) is true
      return {
        ...base,
        from2: '',
      };
    }

    return base;
  })();
};
```

The issue is that I receive the following error:

```
Type '{ unit: string; } | { unit: string; from2: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Fields<Condition>'.
  Type '{ unit: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Fields<Condition>'.ts(2322)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a current [design limitation](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912) of Typescript. It cannot narrow the type of [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) depending on *unspecified* generic type parameter. And while the type parameter is not explicitly specified the type of `Fields<Condition>` is opaque to the compiler.

Usually similar cases *when function returns* a conditional type depending on a generic type parameter are good candidates for rewriting with [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads). But since you're not returning the value of `initialValues` I believe you're better off splitting prop generation into separate branches:

```ts
const BaseComponent = (props: Base) => null
const ExtendedComponent = (props: Extended) => null

const Component = <T extends boolean>(props: Props<T>) => {
  const base = { unit: '' }

  if (props.condition) {
    return <ExtendedComponent {...base} from2="" />
  }

  return <BaseComponent {...base} />
};
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wOakym)

Answer (score -2):

You can simply add the property with a question mark making it as an optional property.

```
unit?: string
```

Comment: I see no reason to do so. This will be incorrect since unit is not optional but depends on Condition.